# Is it possible to include file in config file of zsh? How?

Tags: zsh, alias, configuration

I'd like to have a file eg. *f* with only zsh aliases (pureness reasons). Then I'd like to include *f* file in my *.zshrc* file, so that the aliases defined in *f* are visible in *.zshrc*.

Is it possible?

If it is, I could create a script eg. `my_alias` (`$my_alias ll 'ls -l'`) which appends alias to *f* file.
Of course I could do

```
$echo {alias command} >> ~/.zshrc
```

but this makes *.zshrc* one big mess.

Additionally how is it looks like in bash?

**UPDATE**

If someone share my idea this is solution, thanks to phunehehe:

```
# source aliases
ALIASFILE=~/.aliasesrc
source $ALIASFILE
function add_alias() {
    if [[ -z $1 || -z $2 || $# -gt 2 ]]; then
        echo usage:
        echo "\t\$$0 ll 'ls -l'"
    else
        echo "alias $1='$2'" >> $ALIASFILE
        echo "alias ADDED to $ALIASFILE"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`.zshrc` and `.bashrc` are script files, not config files, so you "source" the alias file. In Zsh (`.zshrc`) and Bash (`.bashrc`) alike:

```
. my_alias
```

will run `my_alias` and leave its effects in the same environment with the RC files, effectively giving you the aliases in the shell. Of course, your are not limited to aliases either. I use a `.shrc` that is sourced by both `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` for common exports, functions and aliases.

For more on sourcing see [Different ways to execute a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/250).

Comment: This does not work. When `~/.zshrc` is a symlink, and `my_alias` is a file in the directory local to the referent file (not located at `~/my_alias`), this command fails. `/Users/me/.zshrc:.:3: no such file or directory: my_aliases`

Answer (score 61):

This is, how I do it in my .zshrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.zsh/zshalias ]; then
    source ~/.zsh/zshalias
else
    print "404: ~/.zsh/zshalias not found."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for good answer, You and phunehehe are correct but it's only possible to approve one answer so I decided to give it to phunehehe becasue he was first :)

Answer (score 23):

To source a file if it exists in one line:

```
[ -f .aliases ] && source .aliases
```

Comment: How is this any different to [pat's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/51824/6761)?

Comment: Same thing but one-liner. I came from google and the one liner was what I was looking for (found it on a forum at the same time) so I thought I might as well share that ;) I wouldn't have been able to come up with it as I'm dumb in bash

Answer (score 4):

After installing [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) the last lines [of `.zshrc`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/templates/zshrc.zsh-template) are:

```
# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.  
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
# 
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

So you have some alternatives:

- Add directly to `.zshrc`
- Create a folder and add at its path at the end of `.zshrc`: `ZSH_CUSTOM=$HOME/Dropbox/.myzshconfig`.
- Use the `~/.oh-my-zsh/custom` folder and `git clone git://github.com/yourusername/zsh_config.git .` there.
- With `source`/dot operator:

  ```bsh
  # CUSTOMIZATION FOR ZSH
  if [ -r ~/Dropbox/.myzshrc ]; then
    source ~/Dropbox/.myzshrc
  fi
  # Or [ -r ~/Dropbox/.myzshrc ] && source ~/Dropbox/.myzshrc
  ```

  `-r FILE` check if exists **and** read permission is granted.

  In this case you could check `$SHELL` to custom bash and zsh including the same file.

### Reference

- [oh-my-zsh - Customization](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Customization)

Comment: Thanks for the Nice idea of Dropboxing it

Answer (score 4):

oh-my-zsh automatically will scan files in the `$ZSH_CUSTOM` directory looking for any that end with `.zsh`. If you create a file called `aliases.zsh` and place it in that directory, it will automatically load those aliases. If you need to override existing oh-my-zsh aliases, then you would configure them at the bottom of the `.zshrc` file.

Comment: best answer. there is also an example.zsh in that folder exactly what I was looking for