# Difference between 3 commands which are used to execute shell script?

Tags: linux, fedora, shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different ways to execute a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/different-ways-to-execute-a-shell-script)

What are the specific differences between the commands listed below?

```
./<scriptname>
. <scriptname>
bash <scriptname>
```

Can anyone explain the differences in simple words, please?

Comment: the commands are 1 ./ scriptname  2 . scriptname 3 bash scriptname

Answer (score 1):

`./<scriptname>` executes `<scriptname>` in a child process and waits for it to exit.

`. <scriptname>` executes `<scriptname>` in the same process; the reasons this is used are usually to allow `<scriptname>` to modify the environment, and to perform additional actions without the resource cost of spawning a new process.

`bash <scriptname>` tells bash to run `<scriptname>`. If `<scriptname>` has a shebang with the path to bash (`#!/bin/bash`) at the top, it will have the same effect as just executing `<scriptname>`. If `<scriptname>` points to another interpreter (`#!/bin/sh`), then `<scriptname>` would normally be interpreted by that program, but you are overriding that by asking bash to interpret it.