# What does sourcing a file mean in a shell?

Tags: shell, shell-script, command

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different ways to execute a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/different-ways-to-execute-a-shell-script)

What happens when I issue the following command:

```
source devenv.csh
```

How does it differ from running it just as `devenv.csh` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you "just run" the file, the interpreter given in the *shebang* (the first line of the script, starting with `#!`, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/csh`) is executed with `devenv` (or `devenv.csh`, this is a bit inconsistent in the question) as a parameter. It will then execute the commands in the file and terminate.

*Sourceing* the file means the commands are executed in the current shell. When some of the commands in `devenv.csh` change the environment (and the file name hints that this is the main purpose of this particular file), executing it will have no effect: the environment will be changed in the subshell, but that will terminate right away, leaving no trace of the changed settings. Note that environment variables never propagate "upward": they can only be inherited by subprocesses, but not by parents.

Comment: And that's why many Gentoo "what if I want the new settings now?" solutions are `source /etc/profile`, not `bash /etc/profile`, and why you use source inside .bashrc and .bash_profile if you want to build on additional files.