# My bash prompt is not working in `screen`

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, prompt

On RedHat, `screen` resets my bash prompt. I set `PS1=\u@\h:\w` in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`.

I added `shell -$SHELL` as well to `~/.screenrc`.

But, when I open a brand new terminal window, the prompt is correct, except in `screen`.

In `screen` I always get this prompt format: `\u@\h>`

How can I set the same prompt in `screen`?

Answer (score 0):

I became so tired of the different startup files for shells that I do this:

- Create a file `~/.shrc` and put all my config in it (including the prompt setting)
- In `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` and whatever file the shell might read, add this line `. ~/.shrc` ([note the dot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/250))
- And finally, forget all about the little details that I never quite grasp

In your case, I suspect that Bash wants `~/.profile` (a wild guess, because as stated above I never got to fully understand those startup files), so adding that might make it work.

Comment: Hello, I put "PS1=\u@\h:\w" into: ~/.shrc, ~/.profile, but the screen still reset my prompt.

Comment: @user2013619 try removing the PS1 settings from the other file if you're doing this.