# Is there a difference between ./script and bash script?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting

Given a shell script file that begins as

```
#!/bin/bash

# (bash script here),
```

and has been `chmod +x`ed, is there any difference in running `./script` and `bash script` from the command-line?

Comment: Also helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/200339/85507

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different ways to execute a shell script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/23408)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on your `$PATH`.  `./script` will run `/bin/bash script`.  `bash script` will use whatever `bash` comes first in your path, which isn't necessarily `/bin/bash`, and could be a different version of Bash.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense; is there a "preferred" or "recommended" way to do it? I've always seen `./script` but recently saw a couple answers on Unix.SE using `bash script`.

Comment: The more generic "bash script" version is useful if you are testing against different versions of bash.  Imagine ~/bin is first in $PATH and ~/bin/bash symlinks to ~/bin/bash_versions/4.2.45/bash or ~/bin/bash_versions/4.1.11/bash or other versions.  If you tried to do the same thing with /bin/bash, you would need to be root (to alter /bin) and would undoubtedly eventually break something in your distro.

Comment: @WChargin People sometimes write `bash script` instead of `./script` in usage instructions so that they don't need to explain how to give `script` execution permissions or what to do on the (non-Linux) systems where `bash` isn't in `/bin`.

Comment: @Gilles Excellent; that clears it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are two differences:

- `./tryit.sh` will not run if bash is not located in `/bin`, but `bash tryit.sh` will run if bash is anywhere on your `PATH`.  This is because `./tryit.sh` will use the shell from the bang path (`/bin/bash`), but `bash tryit.sh` will use the first `bash` shell on the `PATH`.
- `./tryit.sh` will not run if the execute bit is not set, but `bash tryit.sh` will run the script.  You have excluded this case by specifying the bit has been set.  Some edits may clear the bit causing a working command to start failing.

The command `bash tryit.sh` invokes bash telling it that the commands to be executed are found in the file `tryit.sh`.  Many programs such as awk, perl, python, bash, sh, ksh, work in this manner.   This is a standard idom for Unix programs that process command files.

Comment: Can you please point me to something that elaborates on your second point? "`./tryit.sh` will not run if the execute bit is not set, but `bash tryit.sh` will run the script". Documentation? Articles? Anything.

Comment: @Slothworks FWIW, `source tryit.sh` won't care about the status of the `+x` bit either :) In any case, I think the `source` way is much better than using the fairly huge `bash` binary itself to run a script which lacks the `+x` flag. I've never had a situation when I *had* to (mis)use `bash` as a trigger to run such non-executable script.

Comment: @syntaxerror I am aware of `source` being able to do that, with its set of [nuances](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114301/85507) of course. I merely wish to look at some content that expands on @BillThor's second point; maybe elaborating (more than the single line in the answer itself) on why `bash` can run a script which lacks the `+x` flag etc.

Comment: In a nutshell: IMO using `bash` *itself* (instead of its built-in commands) for running a script I'd almost compare to "committing a crime."

Comment: @syntaxerror  See my update.

Answer (score -2):

They are subtly different and easy to make a mistake.

The one you should use (which I'll write in two forms)

```
./script
bash ./script
```

My reasoning is that this is explicit, in case you've changed directory.

non explicit forms

```
script
bash script
```

Are less safe. `bash script` will search the current directory then the directories in the PATH environment variable, `script` by itself is searched only in PATH directories. Running a different command than intended could clobber your files.

Comment: You seem to be answering a different question. The OP is not asking about the difference between `bash script` and `bash script` but `bash ./script` and `./script`. If you run `./script`, your `$PATH` is irrelevant, since you are giving a full path, the shell will never look for `script` in your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Upon re-reading I think you are correct, there's probably a typo in his question " is there a difference between ./script and bash script" which is what I answered

Comment: @XTian No, there isn't a typo - the difference between `./script` and `bash script` is exactly what I'm asking. However, I fail to see how you've answered this. Also, you seem to imply in your answer that simply writing `script` will "look in the current directory for script ... then search through the ... PATH" if it doesn't find it; unless I'm mistaken, I don't believe this is the case. Running `script` will *only* find a file on the path: `$ touch script; $ script; bash: script: command not found`.

Comment: @WChargin Ok, so there isn't a typo, my bad. I'm only trying to warn you that `bash ./script` is much safer than `bash script`. In the latter, if script is not found in your cwd, then the `PATH` is searched, and if found will be used to read commands from (it doesn't even have to e executable!). There's no difference between `./script` vs `bash ./script` but a big difference when `./` is omitted. ps I sometimes come across people with dot in their PATH, you are correct, bash doesn't search for commands there normally.

Answer (score -2):

If I remember correctly from the top of my head, the following two **are** identical:

```
$ ./script
```

and

```
$ source script
```

So using the `./` "command" will in fact **invoke `source` under the hood**, which on its part is a `bash` builtin command. Or, in another interpretation they might be called aliases of each other.
**However**: The first invocation requires you, the user, to set the `+x` (=executable) flag with `chmod` for owner or group, otherwise you will get a "permission denied" error, whilst execution using the `source` command is even possible *without* the `+x` flag. So the latter will sometimes be your life-saver whenever you want to run a `bash` script off an NTFS-formatted pendrive, for instance, since `chmod` cannot work there.

I *think* that will answer your question as well in some way.

Because, for that reason, `bash script` and `source script` cannot be exactly the same; the one is calling the `bash` program *itself* with your script given as a parameter, whilst the other is calling one of `bash`'s *builtin commands* with your script as a parameter.
Though the result will most probably be the same (at least in everyday use), the ways how to get there are somewhat different in both cases.

Comment: Um, ***no***.  **`. `** `script` and `source script` are equivalent in bash and the other shells in which **`.`** and `source` mean the same thing.  `./script` runs the script in a separate process.  `. script` runs the script *in the current shell process*, which (a) might not be bash, and (b) lets the script alter your main shell's environment.  This requires that you have read permission to the script.  `./script` runs the script in a new process, using the interpreter specified in the shebang, provided the user has both read and execute permission.

Comment: Wait a moment...I have __never__ written anything about the `.` *command*. That's yet another pair of shoes. I only mentioned `./script` and `source script` in my answer, but not `. ./script`. Yes it can be confusing at times. Ah, and big thanks for the downvote. :P Yay, that felt so refreshing.