# What is `. command` means and how it works in Linux?

Tags: shell

Example
when start a Virtualenv of python. It will need to type `. someenv/bin/activate`. However, even if it works fine, I still a little bit confuse about how it works.

Is there anyone who can give me a explanation in more general view about `. command` in shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is a synonym to `source` in bash. To sum up, it executes a script *within the current shell*, instead of executing it in a subshell. This means that anything changed in the environment by the script will persist in the shell after the script has ended.

Have a look at this question, which is basically the same as yours : [What's the meaning of a dot before a command in shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell#114301)