# Executing of all shell scripts in a directory starting with the letter 'a'

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have many shell scripts in a directory starting with letter 'a'. How could I execute all of those shell scripts at a shot? Can we develop any other small script to run this?

Answer (score 10):

command line:

```
for each in path_to_directory/a*.sh ; do bash $each ; done
```

example:

```
:~$ ll | grep \.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user      1476 Май 25 16:07 123.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user      1176 Май 25 16:09 222.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user       419 Май 20 14:03 2.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user       191 Май 20 17:50 3.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user         9 Июн  2 11:53 a1.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user         9 Июн  2 11:53 a2.sh

i:~$ cat  q1.sh
echo sadf
:~$ cat  a1.sh
echo 123
:~$ cat  a2.sh
echo 234

:~$ for each in ./a*.sh ; do bash $each ; done
123
234
```

OR you can use a command line utility called run-parts. This tool can automatically discover multiple scripts or programs in a directory, and run them all.

For example, to run all scripts in /etc whose names start with 'a' and end with '.sh':

```
$ run-parts --regex '^a.*\.sh$' /etc
```

With "--test" option, you can print the names of the scripts which would be executed, without actually running them. This is useful for testing purpose

```
$ run-parts --test ./my_script_directory
```

Comment: I think just `do ./"$each"`, or even `do "$each"` would suffice, no?

Comment: yes, if scripts are executable (chmox +x) =). In my example - no

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm /111 -name 'a*' -exec {} \;
```

or

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -name 'a*' -exec {} \;
```

Either of these will find all filenames beginning with `a` in the current directory (but not subdirectories) with owner, group, or other execution bit(s) set, and try to run them.

I say "try" because the attempt may fail, e.g., if only the owner and group execution bits are set AND you are neither the owner nor a member of the group.  In that case, you would have no permission to execute the file.

Another possible failure mode is that it can only execute scripts that can be interpreted by your current shell.  so an `awk` or `perl` etc script beginning with `a` won't run - it will fail with syntax errors because they're not shell scripts.

---

Another method is:

```
for f in ./a* ; do [ -x "$f" ] && [ ! -d "$f" ] && "$f" ; done
```

That will execute anything beginning with `a` that is executable by you (and is NOT a directory), no matter what kind of executable it is - shell script, awk script, perl script, binary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
for i in a*; do file "$i"|grep -q 'script' && ./"$i"; done
```

**Explanation**-

1. `for i ...` - This is a for loop which will iterate over every item that starts with a.
2. `file "$i"|grep ...` **file** command displays the type of the file. This is necessary because there may be other files or directories starting with 'a'. The **grep** looks for the word '**script**' in the output of file
3. `&& ./"$i" ...` If the search by **grep** is successful, it executes the script.

Comment: I should execute this in linux? Will it work?

Comment: Not recommended.  Why `source` if you just want to run the script?

Comment: @vamsikrishna Yes

Comment: @Wildcard What do you recommend?

Comment: Perhaps `for f in a*; do file "$f" | grep -q script && ./"$f"; done`.  Also note the [quoting of variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943).

Comment: @Wildcard I thought `source` and `.` does the same thing. is there any difference?

Comment: `. scriptname` and `source scriptname` are the same (in bash), but `./scriptname` is completely different.  In the last case `.` simply means "the current directory."  Also see ["Different ways to execute a shell script."](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2976/135943)