# Setting up environment variables with .sh file

Tags: shell, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have created env.sh file the contents of which are below

```
#!/bin/sh

export M2_HOME=/vagrant/tools/maven
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_65
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.9.7
export MAVEN_HOME=$M2_HOME
```

but executing this sh file does not result in env variables being exported. Have to manually execute each line to get them exported. Please help

Comment: The duplicate marking is correct.  Note that [the answer there that is most applicable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2979/135943) is not the top voted one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to `source` (`.`) the file, not execute:

```
. env.sh
```

When you execute the script, it is run in a subshell, and all the parameters exported will go out of scope once the (sub)shell exits, not affecting the parent shell.

When you `source` it, the parameters will be available on the calling session. And also on the child processes as you are `export`-ing them.

---

Note that, the default system shell (`sh`) for Ubuntu is `dash`, not `bash` and `gnome-terminal` spawns `bash` as the interactive shell. While executing, make sure the shebang is correct, and desired one. Also while `source`-ing, no need for the shebang, you can drop it.

Comment: To further clarify: `export` makes a variable available to *sub*processes of the shell that it's exported from (i.e. subshells, commands run from that shell, etc). There is no way to push a variable up to the *parent* process of the shell. Environment variables always flow down the process tree, never up.